# How can I listen to console events in symfony?

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to hook into symfonys console events with the symfony standard edition (2.3), but it just won't work.

I created a listener according to their [example](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/events.html) and follow the [guides on event registration](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html):

```
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Event\ConsoleCommandEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Console\ConsoleEvents;

class AcmeCommandListener
{
    public function onConsoleCommand(ConsoleCommandEvent $event) {
        // get the output instance
        $output = $event->getOutput();

        // get the command to be executed
        $command = $event->getCommand();

        // write something about the command
        $output->writeln(sprintf('Before running command <info>%s</info>', $command->getName()));
    }
}
```

and someone on the mailing list told me to register it as event in the service container. So I did this:

```
services:
    kernel.listener.command_dispatch:
        class: Acme\DemoBundle\EventListener\AcmeCommandListener
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: console.command }
```

But obviously the tagging is not correct and I can't find the correct names for that. How would I do that?

Comment: Are you using `php app/console` or a custom application?

Comment: I'm using the standard edition of Symfony and want to add a event firing before a `app/console` command is executed. I already asked in the symfony google group and someone said I need to configure it using a service (as I tried above).

Answer (score 3):

```
Platform\EventListener\Console\InitListener:
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: console.command, priority: 1024 }

<?php 
class CustomListener
{
    public function onConsoleCommand(ConsoleCommandEvent $event): void
    {
        //do somehting
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tags

Answer (score 1):

So, I finally got it. The above code in the original post ist fully working, but I defined my services.yml within my bundle not in the application config `app/config.yml`. This means, the configuration was never loaded. I had to import the configuration via container extensions:

```
# Acme/DemoBundle/DependencyInjection/AcmeDemoExtension.php
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader;

class AcmeDemoExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.yml');
    }
}
```

and

```
# Acme/DemoBundle/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\TreeBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\ConfigurationInterface;

class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
        $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('headwork_legacy');
        return $treeBuilder;
    }
}
```

Though I guess you can even leave out the `$configuration = new Configuration();` part and the `Configuration` class.

Answer (score 1):

Your `tags` event listener name must be a `console.event_listener`. It's has helped me to resolve this issue.

```
services:
    kernel.listener.command_dispatch:
        class: Acme\DemoBundle\EventListener\AcmeCommandListener
        tags:
            - { name: console.event_listener, event: console.command }
```